# Downloading Javax Communications API

Tags: java, maven, serial-port, serial-communication, javax.comm

Does anyone know where I can download the Java communications API?  On the repo1.maven.org it says to download it from http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=43208d3d but that redirects you to Oracle's new download site and then it's nowhere to be found.

Are there any alternatives to javax.comm to read data from a com port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't available any longer (and hasn't been for some years).

You may be able to find old versions of it out on the net but your results may vary in trying to use it with current java and OSes.

**EDIT:** [RXTX](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/) seems to be something people are still using, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: So there isn't official alternative to RxTx anymore? It makes panda sad panda.